# Path for all users

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I am developing an application in Eclipse using Java11. I have created a path, but this path is specific to my system.

```
file://D:/my_proj/darp/src/test/resources/rmtrep
```

I want a general path in order to have the project working on other computer as well without changing this variable .

The string which contains the path is used here, like this:

```
public void my_file(String string) {
        myFile = URI.create(string);
    }
```

What I want to do is using the file path like this:

```
file://darp/src/test/resources/rmtrep
```

and in function my_file to work with the string in order to get the result as the full path, like this: `file://D:/my_proj/darp/src/test/resources/rmtrep`
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Based on the path, what you have is not a file but a _resource_. Conceptually the two are different (even if the resource is sometimes a file under-the-hood). Use the API for accessing resources (e.g. `Class#getResource(String)`, `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you, but this not really solve my task, the path will not work with if I use "file://"

Comment: Of course not. But if what you have is a resource then `file://` is wrong anyway. Read the documentation of the API I mentioned to see what syntax the argument uses.

Comment: By the way, if what you need is a `URI` then you can simply do `getResource(...).toURI()`. When the resource is a file you'll get a `file://` URI. When the resource is packaged in a JAR you'll get a `jar:file//` URI.

Comment: But "rmtrep" is a folder, and I get null pointer exeception when I try to use it. the string is not null, but the getResource(string) returns null

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps this is an XY problem. What are you actually trying to solve? What does getting access to this folder give you?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

use relative pathing, assuming your root directory for your project is my_proj:

```
File file = new File("/darp/src/test/resources/rmtrep");
```

Comment: The path won't work with "file://" in front and I can't get rid of that. Thank you for your answer